# I make a list of URL of different pages for scraping the data. Can anyone tell me that is there any way to automate this process?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

urls = ['https://www.trustpilot.com/categories/restaurants_bars? 
 numberofreviews=0&status=all&timeperiod=0', 
'https://www.trustpilot.com/categories/restaurants_bars? 
numberofreviews=0&page=2&status=all&timeperiod=0',
'https://www.trustpilot.com/categories/restaurants_bars? 
numberofreviews=0&page=3&status=all&timeperiod=0',
'https://www.trustpilot.com/categories/restaurants_bars? 
numberofreviews=0&page=4&status=all&timeperiod=0',
'https://www.trustpilot.com/categories/restaurants_bars? 
numberofreviews=0&page=5&status=all&timeperiod=0',
'https://www.trustpilot.com/categories/restaurants_bars? 
numberofreviews=0&page=6&status=all&timeperiod=0',
'https://www.trustpilot.com/categories/restaurants_bars? 
numberofreviews=0&page=7&status=all&timeperiod=0',
'https://www.trustpilot.com/categories/restaurants_bars? 
numberofreviews=0&page=8&status=all&timeperiod=0']
for url in URLs:
    html_text = requests.get(url).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, 'lxml')
    restaurants = soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'categoryBusinessListWrapper___14CgD')
    for index, restaurant in enumerate(restaurants):
        tags = restaurant.find_all('a', class_ = 'internal___1jK0Z wrapper___26yB4')
        for tag in tags:
            restaurant_name = tag.find('div', class_ = 'businessTitle___152-c').text.split(',')[0]
            ratings = tag.find('div', class_ = 'textRating___3F1NO')
            location = tag.find('span', class_ = 'locationZipcodeAndCity___33EfU')
            more_info = tag['href']
```

As you can see that I create a URLs list to store the URL of different pages on this website. Is there any process to automate this? I use BeautifulSoup and the request module for scraping. I want to know that if there is any process to automate the URL accessing for different pages.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the pagination at the bottom of the page and use list comprehension to create those links:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

url = 'https://www.trustpilot.com/categories/restaurants_bars?numberofreviews=0&status=all&timeperiod=0'
regex = re.compile('pagination')

response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
pages = len(soup.find_all("a", {"class": regex}))

links = ['https://www.trustpilot.com/categories/restaurants_bars?numberofreviews=0&page={page}&status=all&timeperiod=0'.format(page=page+1) for page in range(0,pages) ]
```

**Output:**

```
print (links)

['https://www.trustpilot.com/categories/restaurants_bars?numberofreviews=0&page=1&status=all&timeperiod=0', 'https://www.trustpilot.com/categories/restaurants_bars?numberofreviews=0&page=2&status=all&timeperiod=0', 'https://www.trustpilot.com/categories/restaurants_bars?numberofreviews=0&page=3&status=all&timeperiod=0', 'https://www.trustpilot.com/categories/restaurants_bars?numberofreviews=0&page=4&status=all&timeperiod=0', 'https://www.trustpilot.com/categories/restaurants_bars?numberofreviews=0&page=5&status=all&timeperiod=0', 'https://www.trustpilot.com/categories/restaurants_bars?numberofreviews=0&page=6&status=all&timeperiod=0', 'https://www.trustpilot.com/categories/restaurants_bars?numberofreviews=0&page=7&status=all&timeperiod=0', 'https://www.trustpilot.com/categories/restaurants_bars?numberofreviews=0&page=8&status=all&timeperiod=0']
```